# How to Customize the Release names in VSTS?

Tags: xml, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on DevOps with VSTS. I configured the release definition without build definition and whenever the developer commit the code into Git it automatically release triggered.

Currently, my Release name format will be looks like “Project-$(rev:r)” below image.
[image]
But I want to display the project version like “**Project - 1.1.12.01**” in the Release name format instead of “**Project-$(rev:r)**”. For that I have XML file in my code it contains following lines of code.

```
<buildInfo>
  <version>1.1.12.01</version>
</buildInfo>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to read the version tag information in above XML file and put that value in Release name format under the Options of Release Defintion?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t update the release name, but this feature has been added to the backlog, check this issue: [Updating a Release Name](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1303)